# blur image border flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface

I'm looking for a way to replicate the effect showcased in the image provided using Flutter. Here's the example image: example image : -

[image]

I want the image to blend smoothly with the background.

I attempted using `ClipPath`, but unfortunately, it didn't yield the desired results.